# How to premine DOT on a local private network (local devnet)

Tags: polkadot, docker

I'm setting up a local-testnet with multiple nodes and would like to know if there is a way to premine DOT without using the UI
Here is a copy of my docker-compose from following the steps on https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot

```
version: '2'

services:
  polkadot:
    container_name: polkadot
    image: parity/polkadot
    # volumes:
    #   - /my/local/folder:/polkadot
    command: [
      # "--name", "PolkaDocker",
      # "--ws-external",
      # "--rpc-external", #must need
      # "--rpc-cors", "all"
      "--chain=polkadot-local",
      "--alice", "-d", "/tmp/alice",
      "--node-key", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
    ]
    networks:
      polkadotnw:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.10
  polkadot2:
    container_name: polkadot2
    image: parity/polkadot
    # volumes:
    #   - /my/local/folder:/polkadot
    command: [
      # "--name", "PolkaDocker",
      # "--ws-external",
      # "--rpc-external",
      # "--rpc-cors", "all"
      "--chain=polkadot-local", 
      "--bob", "-d", "/tmp/bob", 
      "--bootnodes", "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWHdiAxVd8uMQR1hGWXccidmfCwLqcMpGwR6QcTP6QRMuD"
    ]
    networks:
      polkadotnw:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.20
    depends_on:
      - polkadot


networks:
  polkadotnw:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you want to author and finalise blocks on the local testnet of a Substrate-based chain like Polkadot then you need at least three validators, not just two. so add a third Docker container called polkadot3 and use "well known" pre-funded account `--charlie`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the chain-spec of you local test net [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/5a43bc733024b6f2d4f1164db8991a393c8e14cb/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L308). The *endowed* accounts are accounts with a pre-mined balance.
There is an example of how to put in an AccountID in the [Westend](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/5a43bc733024b6f2d4f1164db8991a393c8e14cb/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L403) chain-spec.